# How can I check type of multiple variables in one block?

Tags: autohotkey

How can I check the type of multiple variables in one `if` statement block, without using several `if` statements? Example:

```
If var1 is not integer
{
    MsgBox, 0, Error, var1 is not integer
    Return
}
If var2 is not integer
{
    MsgBox, 0, Error, var2 is not integer
    Return
}
```

What I would like to do is check the types in a single boolean expression.

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
if ((var1 is not integer) or (var2 is not integer))
{
    MsgBox, 0, Error, variables are not integers
    Return
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `and`, not `or`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Or is correct in my case. I am checking for two different integer values (at least they're expected to be). I want to terminate the script if either of them are not. And please update the status.. What exactly is unclear about it? What other information is needed?

Comment: I check your code in several ways but it seems that that kind of `if` statement does not allow to use parentheses `()` . So I think you can only check one variable per one `if` statement. Also, you can use nested `if` statements.

Comment: I said `or` was correct! A nested if statement works exactly like an `and` statement... Geez.

Answer (score 2):

Special `If` commands in AHK like `If var [not] between` , `If var [not] in/contains MatchList`, **`If var is [not] type`**, `IfWin...` aren't actual boolean expressions, so you can't *chain* them using boolean operators.
However, these conditional statements can be wrapped in a function. Furthermore, `If var is [not] type` can be rebuilt using RegEx:

## Solution 1: Wrapper function

```
isInteger(arg) {
    if arg is integer
        return true
    else
        return false
}

if(isInteger(123) && isInteger(456)) {
    MsgBox, yay!
}
```

## Solution 2: RegEx

```
if(RegExMatch(123, "^\d+$") && RegExMatch(456, "^\d+$")) {
    msgbox, hooray!
}
```

## Some tests

If you're interested, take a look at the array values, copy the script and run it. You may find some results surprising. Both our wrapper function and `RegExMatch` provide the same back-to-back results.

```
arr := [123, 456, 123.456, "789", "not_an_integer!", true, false]
msg := ""
Loop % arr.MaxIndex()
{
    msg .= arr[A_Index]
    msg .= ":`tisInteger(): " isInteger(arr[A_Index])
    msg .= " RegExMatch(): " RegExMatch(arr[A_Index], "^\d+$")
    msg .= "`n"
}
msgbox  % msg


isInteger(arg) {
    if arg is integer
        return true
    else
        return false
}
```

Comment: @JoeDF Could you elaborate? If you mean some type of variadic function, I'm not aware that AHK supports such a syntax.